Why do some molecular compounds exhibit long coherence times?
I recently came across a few papers (notably this paper) that discuss the usage of certain molecules as qubits due to long coherence times. These papers usually gloss over what contributes to longer coherence times and what informs the construction of these molecules.
What I'm particularly curious about is how particular properties and/or chemical functionalization contribute to decoherence and if there are any good resources on learning more about this.

If a spin is isolated either from a molecule's  internal magnetic fields (due to other electrons) or from that produced by the spins in the solvent then the coherence time of an ensemble of such spins will be long, and vice versa. Molecular motion should also be important.

This paper talks about salts of chelated ions. Calling them "molecular compounds" is at least imprecise... I think this q. would be better off on Physics.se

There's also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/
